# Lifetime of database created using EF Code First

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, database, entity-framework

Having created a Database using EF Code First, I'm curious how long the records stay in the database that I add to it? When stopping the debugger, the records are still there so it's not like they only exist while the program is running.

But say I create 10000 records now. Can I rely on the database not being deleted or its records when I e.g. switch off the computer? Or will the database in fact stay as I leave it? Then assuming I'm connected to the database, any future operations executed from my program will just alter the existing database and all its records?

I'm just confused about the scope of the lifetime of the database that I'm thinking of adding a lot of data to.

Comment: If you've attached it to a SQL Server database, then the data should be persistent.

Comment: Usually RDBMS' guarantee Durability: if you saved the data and commited transaction - data remains persisted. Until the moment you delete the data.

Comment: The lifetime of the database depends on the lifetime of the disk on which it is stored.  If you want to preserve the data longer than that, you should be certain to have a robust backup plan.

Comment: I'm confused by the question, it's tagged as SQL server so it's a database server - are you asking if the data is going to randomly delete itself from the database!? SQL Server isn't an in memory database - it stores it's data in files on the hard drive so assuming you don't delete the MDB file, it will stay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***It Depends*** on what Database Initialization Strategy you have, in your Code-First code.

For instance, if you have it set to `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges` and change the model in your C# code by adding or removing Properties and then run the Project, it will `DROP` the database, **essentially deleting all the records you have in all the tables**, and recreate an empty database with the new schema.

If you don't want to lose the data that you add, you should either programatically add the data by overriding the `Seed()` method, or Create a **Visual Studio Database Project**, and import the Schema and data into it. The 1st method of seeding data is cleaner and more maintainable as you make updates to your DB models.

Here are the other **Database Initialization Strategies in Code-First**.

1. `CreateDatabaseIfNotExists`: This is default initializer. As name suggests, it will create the database if not exists as per the configuration. However, if you change the model class and then run the application with this initializer then it will throw an exception.
2. `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges`: This initializer drops existing database and creates new database if your model classes (entity classes) have been changed. So you don’t have to worry about maintaining your database schema when your model classes changes.
3. `DropCreateDatabaseAlways`: As name suggests, this initializer drops an existing database every time you run the application irrespective of whether your model classes have changed or not. This will be useful when you want fresh database every time you run the application while developing.
4. Custom DB Initializer: You can also create your own custom initializer if any of the above doesn’t satisfy your requirement or you want to do some other process when it initialize the database using above initializer.

Source: [entityframeworktutorial.net / Database Initialization Strategies in Code-First](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/database-initialization-strategy-in-code-first.aspx)